# How to print enum values as strings in fortran?

Tags: enums, fortran, gfortran, fortran2008

I have defined an enum UNIT as below in fortran and want to print the values as strings instead of numbers.

```
public :: UNIT,E_TIME_STEP,E_DAY,E_WEEK,E_MONTH,E_YEAR
ENUM , BIND(C)
ENUMERATOR :: UNIT=0
ENUMERATOR :: E_TIME_STEP
ENUMERATOR :: E_DAY
ENUMERATOR :: E_WEEK
ENUMERATOR :: E_MONTH
ENUMERATOR :: E_YEAR
END ENUM
```

I have a function which reads a string value ("TIME_STEP", "DAY", etc) from a file and returns the corresponding enum value (E_TIME_STEP, E_DAY, etc).

This works properly without any issues during the read. However I don't store the string value anywhere while reading, and after reading I have only the enum value (E_TIME_STEP, E_DAY, etc). While printing it to the console I need to print the string instead of the number. Is it possible to get the string without storing it in the fist place.?

I have added two functions of which one takes the input string ("TIME_STEP, "DAY, etc) and returns the enum name (UNIT) and the second function which takes enum name and enum value (UNIT, 1 to 5) and returns the enum string ("TIME_STEP", "DAY", etc) which doesn't make sense as I am again storing enum name in a local variable. Is it possible to get the string without storing it even locally?

Comment: I don't think you can, I think you need a programming language with [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) or at least [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) to do that, and afaik Fortran has neither. I would create a function `to_string` that takes an integer input and returns the corresponding string using a `select case` clause.

Comment: Thanks @chw21, that is what I am doing currently to get the strings using a select statement with the integer input. I will stick with it for a while till I find some other way to do this.

Comment: The only improvement I can see is to generate the code programmatically, for instance with a scripting language, to avoid manual editing of the code.